Find the radius of convergence for $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^{n!}$
Find the radius of convergence for $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^{n!}$. Here's my work so far:
Let $f(z) = z^{n!}$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$. My question doesn't convern how to find the radius of convergence, but instead how to calculate the $a_k$'s, i.e. the values
$$a_k = \frac{f^{(k)}(z)}{k!}$$
Now, we note that
\begin{align}
    \begin{split}
        f(0)&= 0^{n!}=0\\
        f'(0) &= n! \cdot 0^{n!-1}= 0  \\
        f''(0) &= n!(n!-1) \cdot 0^{n!-2} = 0 \\
f'''(0) &= n!(n!-1)(n!-2) \cdot 0^{n!-3} = 0 \\
        \vdots  \\
    \end{split}
\end{align}
And we notice that $f^{(k)}(0) = 0$ for all $k < n!$, but when we get to $n!$, we observe that
$$f^{(n!)}(0) = n!(n!-1) \dots (n!-(n!-1)) \cdot 0^{n! -n!}$$
I found a solution online that $a_k=1$ when $k=n!$ and is $0$ otherwise. I clearly see that "and is $0$ otherwise" part, but I'm struggling to see how $k=n!$ implies that $a_k=1$. Surely, $0^{n!-n!} = 0^0=1$ as in above, but explicitly, we have
\begin{align}
\begin{split}
a_{n!}= \frac{f^{(n!)}(0)}{n!} &= \frac{n!(n!-1) \dots (n!-(n!-1))}{n!} \cdot 0^{n! -n!} \\
&= n!(n!-1) \dots (n!-(n!-1)) \cdot 0^0 \\
&= n!(n!-1) \dots 1 \neq 1
\end{split}
\end{align}
Is there an error I have made? I fail to see how $k=n!$ implies $a_k=1$

The denominator in the expression for $a_{n!}$ should be $(n!)!$.

In the last equation, the denominator is wrong: If you substitute $n!$ for $k$, then the denominator will be $(n!)!$.
\begin{align}
\begin{split}
a_{n!}= \frac{f^{(n!)}(0)}{(n!)!} &= \frac{n!(n!-1) \dots (n!-(n!-1))}{n!} \cdot 0^{n! -n!} \\
&= \frac{n!(n!-1) \dots 1}{(n!)!} \cdot 0^0 \\
&= \frac{(n!)!}{(n!)!} \cdot 1 \\
&= 1
\end{split}
\end{align}

Oh my goodness, thank you so much. That clears it up!
